# Wrong OrderBy in Sql query ordered in opposite way

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to order by Integer but it seemed that it order by the larger to the smaller number but it order by 2-digit then 3-digit
sc is the score i need to order

Code i used

```
SELECT * FROM `users`  ORDER BY `sc`  DESC
```

The result are :
47
3
102

Comment: Datatype for sc? Seems to be character...

Comment: the data type is varchar(10)

Comment: binary character '4' > binary character '3' > binary character  '1'.  Seems ordered fine if data is character. Perhaps you need to cast it to numeric before ordering? or padd with leading zeros so it compares "more" correctly...

Comment: Then you'll get alphanumeric ordering. If you want numeric, you need to use a number type (or pad with zeroes in front).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use silent conversion to integer as

```
select * from users order by sc+0 desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like datetype of `sc` is char/varchar. You have to [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) it to an integer:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`  ORDER BY cast(`sc` as UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`  ORDER BY CAST(`sc` AS SIGNED INTEGER) DESC
```